# Why does FindFit seem to have trouble fitting exponential data?

Tags: fitting

I have 4 data points. t is in minutes, and y is radioactive counts per minute. When I input the following lines:

```
data = {{90., 140075.}, {120., 96018.}, {150., 73003.}, {180., 36980.}};
model = a*Exp[-k*t];
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, k}, t]
```

the output given is:

```
{a -> 64.6435, k -> 0.29285}
```

This is clearly not correct. The parameter 'a' should be somewhere around 530000 (as per Excel's fitted equation). What's happening here, and how can I fix this? I'm surprised a bit. This is a simple exponential fit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try providing a reasonable initial guess: `fit = FindFit[data, model, {{a, Last@Mean[data]}, {k, 1/First@Mean[data]}}, t]`

Answer (score 6):

```
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, k}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested to know that we are working on a `FindSimpleFit` function that is intended to automate the finding of many common classes of curve, exponentials obviously included. This is similar to what Wolfram|Alpha Pro [currently does](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20&examplefile=1&datasetfile=DataInput%2Fdates-numbers) when you upload a dataset that looks like a timeseries or scatterplot. Automation for the win!

Answer (score 3):

As has been already commented you can specify `Method` or specify approximate parameter values as per Rahul Narain's comment.

You can also use `NonlinearModelFit`,e.g.:

```
nlm=NonlinearModelFit[data, {a Exp[- k t]}, {{a, 53000}, {k, 1/100}}, t]
```

yields :448761. E^(-0.0128453 t)

Visualizing fit:

```
Plot[nlm[t], {t, 80, 200}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

For this specific problem you could transform data and use `LinearModelFit` and back transform.

```
tdata = {#1, Log@#2} & @@@ data
lm = LinearModelFit[tdata, {1, t}, t]
btf = Exp[Normal@lm]
{Exp[#1], #2} & @@ lm["BestFitParameters"]
```

The last expression yielding back transformed parameters: {530142., -0.0142315}

```
Plot[btf, {t, 90, 200}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]},
  PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {90, 19000}]
```

[image]

There are a lot of related (perhaps duplicate) questions that provide valuable information. I suggest looking at them also.

Comment: Is the only difference between `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` the fact that the latter provides more statistical information, or is there anything deeper than that?

Comment: @RahulNarain I do not know the answer to the specific question. I frequently use `NonlinearModelFit` to look at quantification of model fit, reasonableness of assumptions, look for systematic error in residuals...as well as the "glorious p-values"...there seems to be a lot of intersection...both seems to accept methods...

Comment: @RahulNarain I believe that FindFit minimizes, e.g. the  least squares error, whereas NonlinearModelFit maximizes the value of the parameter values with respect to a likelihood function.